# What poem was the inspiration for Rachmaninoff's duet Suite 1 Op 5 mvmt III?

Tags: piano

My understanding is that the poem is by Tyutchev, and is called Tears, but for some reason I can't find an English translation of this poem. The fact that I can't find it makes me think I have the author or title wrong.  So... Any help?

Comment: Hi. This question might not be on topic here, but it will definitely be on topic on the Music Fans SE. Please commit to the proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans, in order to make it to beta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's Nabokov's translation:

> Human tears. O the tears! you that flow when life is begun - or
>   half-gone, tears unseen, tears unknown, you that none can number or
>   drain, you that run like the streamlets of rain from the low clowds of
>   Autumn, long before dawn...

It's available in "[Verses and Versions: Three Centuries of Russian Poetry](http://books.google.com/books?id=nbyY09mwF9oC&lpg=PA413&ots=NwZmbTdopp&dq=%22Fyodor%20Tyutchev%22%20the%20tears&pg=PA253#v=onepage&q=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B&f=false)," edited by Brian Boyd and Stanislav Shvabrin.

Here's the original Russian as published on the piece:

> Слёзы людские, о слёзы людские,
>   Льётесь вы ранней и поздней порой…
>   Льётесь безвестные, льётесь незримые,
>   Неистощимые, неисчислимые, —
>   Льётесь, как льются струи дождевые
>   В осень глухую порою ночной.

Also worth noting, Nikolai Tcherepnin set this poem in his Four Songs, Op. 16 — you might be able to find CD notes that provide a less poetic translation than Nabokov's.

Answer (score 2):

this is actually 4 different poets

I. Barcarolle (poem by Mikhail Lermontov)
At dusk the chill wave laps gently
Beneath the gondola's slow oar.
That song again and again, the twang of the guitar…
In the distance the old barcarolle was heard,
now melancholy, now happy…
The gondola glides through the water, and time glides over the surge of love;
The water will grow smooth again and passion will rise no more.

II. The Night … the Love ("Parisina" by Lord Byron)
It is the hour when from the boughs
The nightingale’s high note is heard;
It is the hour when lovers’ vows
Seem sweet in every whisper’d word;
And gentle winds, and waters near,
Make music to the lonely ear.

She listens — but not for the nightingale —
Though her ear expects as soft a tale.
There glides a step through the foliage thick,
And her cheek grows pale — and her heart beats quick.
There whispers a voice through the rustling leaves,
And her blush returns, and her bosom heaves:
A moment more — and they shall meet —
‘Tis past — her lover’s at her feet.

And heedless as the dead are they
Of aught around, above, beneath;
As if all else had passed away,
They only for each other breathe;
Their very sighs are full of joy
So deep, that did it not decay,
That happy madness would destroy
The hearts which feel its fiery sway.

III. Tears (poem by Fyodor Tyutchev)
Tears, human tears
You flow both early and late —
You flow unknown, you flow unseen
Inexhaustible, innumerable —
You flow like torrents of rain
In the depths of an autumn night.

IV. Easter (poem by Alexei Khomyakov)
Across the earth a mighty bell is ringing
Until all the booming air rocks like the sea
As silver thunderings sing forth the tidings
Exulting in that holy victory…

my sister performed this suite with her dual piano parther back in the mid 90s, and brings me literally to tears